# updating total_counts Column vs SELECT COUNT(*) Query

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 tables

```
feeds
=====
id int
content text

feed_likes
=====
id int
feed_id int
like_by int
```

I want to get total feed likes: 2 ways

1. `Select (count(*) from feed_likes) as total_likes From feeds`
2. I will add a column in feeds table e.g total_likes and when someone like this feed then I will increment it. so this will be retrive in `Select * From Feeds`.

Now the question is which one is Best ?
and which one is being used by Facebook?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1- It seems that you want total likes **by feed** so the correct query would be :

```
SELECT count(*) as total_likes, feed_id FROM feed_likes GROUP BY feed_id
```

2- It's a very bad idea, you are breaking a logical design here as the table for the like is feed_likes not feed.

I don't know how facebook manage it but I am pretty sure that they don't add a COUNT column. The query i write is quite simple as you can see it so you don't need to store the value.

Comment: Daniel i am asking for best option.
Query will be executed everytime to get total feeds count.

Comment: And i answered, don't use option 2 !